nuxt3 $fetch did not catch http 401 response as expected
I was working on Nuxt3 and trying to get http 401 status code to refresh my access token.
This is what I do in @/utils/useApi.js
try { 
    let apiData = await $fetch(url, fetchOpts)
        .then((res) => {
            if (res.status == '200') {
                return res
            } else {
                // I was expecting http 401 response goes here
            }

        }).catch(async e => {
            // but it goes here, no idea how to get http status
        })
    return apiData
} catch (e) {
    console.error('api error: ', e)
}

I was expecting it to go into .then(), but it goes to catch().
How does this work?
Did I do anything wrong?
Or how can I get HTTP status in catch?

Update my error information.
This is what I got from e.
I cannot see useful data from my console, but can do e.status to get HTTP status.


401 is an error, it hence goes into the most nested catch block of the function calling it.
then is used in case of a fulfillment. More info on Promises here.
Check the content of your e in the catch block to have more details about the error.
Also, I recommend not mixing async with: await and .then, use one or the other.

Thanks for your reply. I have updated the content of my e on my question.
How can I get more information about the e?

@cony I am not sure what you have in your e object but that's pretty much the info you have. $fetch is using ofetch under the hood, so any kind of configuration regarding the errors could be set, checked in the same way as the Github readme explains it.
